# How do I connect to the openfire server?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

How do I connect to *openfire* server as a client ? I have installed *openfire* on my machine and want to connect to the server from another machine.

Both the machines are on the same *LAN*. Basically I want to create a new user by signing up.

Answer (score 1):

It is depend on client api. I used [smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp). In smack API, you can use `org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration` for connection.

The default port is 9090 for the web-based admin console of open-fire server.

```
http://127.0.0.1:9090
```

Try as below example :

```
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("localhost", 5222);
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
```

[Smack Getting Started](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/gettingstarted.html)

**Update** You need to plugin to Openfire Server for [User Service](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp).

Comment: I am using a web-browser to connect. Like I want to register a new user with openfire

Comment: @saplingPro You mean ` web-based admin console`? Check my updated answer. Make sure to do your browser proxy setting.

Comment: I am sorry but I guess you didn't read the question properly. I said I want to connect to the server from another machine. Like I want to register a new user to the openfire server

Comment: will you further comment on the above comment ?

Answer (score 0):

@saplingPro I think there is a confusion about what OpenFire is.

> Openfire is an open-source XMPP server.

This means it provides the means to handle XMPP protocol connections. Those would be done by "chat client implementations" . But the server does not provide the implementation itself, only the backend for that. 
If you are looking for a webchat, you can take a look at this:

https://rocket.chat/